# From the moment, to the moment sequence

Tags: prepositions, commas

> We’ve learned a lot from the moment we started, opened in beta, to the moment we launched.

Is this correct? It reads a bit awkward to have "opened in beta" between the from and to moments.

How would you phrase it better?

Comment: What do you intend the sentence to say? Is "opened in beta" meant to be a clarification of the "moment we started"?

Comment: No. It's meant to be three moments: when we started, when we opened in beta, and when we launched.

Comment: Since the time range from the moment you started to the moment you launched would automatically include the moment you opened in beta, it seems to me that you could drop the middle term without any loss of meaning.

Comment: Thanks @KillingTime! Would you have an alternative phrasing that would highlight the three main "stages"? It's for a press release, and the beta stage is a huge part of our journey.

Comment: If you replace "opened in beta" with "through opening in beta" the meaning would be clearer.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Appreciate it.